# Autofac - How to dispose the root lifetime?

Tags: windows-services, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I'm using Autofac as the IoC container for a windows service.

I have a class `ConnectionManager` registered as a singleton (and thus, tied into the *root lifetime scope* of Autofac).

The IoC container is configured and initialized in the service's `OnStart()` method. The usual stuff:

```
private IContainer _container;

public void OnStart()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //initialize it...

    _container = builder.Build();
}
```

I want to make sure the (singleton) instance of `ConnectionManager` is disposed when the service is stopped - namely when the `OnStop()` method is called. 
I want to tell the Autofac container: "Nice meeting you. Now [prepare to die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JGp7Meg42U)."

My question is: How can I get my hands on the root lifetime scope in the `OnStop()` method so I can dispose of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face.

The container itself IS the root lifetime scope. So dispose of the container to get the singletons disposed...

```
public void OnStop()
{
    _container.Dispose();
}
```